# Anchor hash tag link spacing in newsletters

Tags: html, hyperlink, anchor, newsletter

How can I add space to an anchor hash tag link in newsletters?
I'm adding named anchors, and inline I add following css:

```
<a href="#article-1">Go to article</a>

<a name="article-1" style="display:block;margin-top: -100px;height: 400px;visibility:hidden;"></a>
```

In the online version of the newsletter, this works, but not in Outlook. Is it also possible to do this in newsletters?

Comment: Can we see the online version? How are you sending out the newsletter?

Comment: do you want space before "Go to article"??

Comment: The e-mail is sent with Outlook, no other sending tool available unfortunately. I want to add space to the <a name="article-1">-link.

Comment: Here's the online version: http://messagent.roulartamail.be/optiext/optiextension.dll?ID=gULgM0ojfM8ISuQs9isndQRrPB4XOBaVp013HTJDUwCVLzFw3uGjBwqq6gody84aapVxELawF%2BupCq8P60